# Density of States of electrons with tight binding and a Zeeman term in the Hamiltonian

Tags: solid-state-physics, density-of-states

Should density of states for electrons always be symmetric?

The Hamiltonian I am considering is:

$$
H= \Sigma_{<i,j>,\sigma} -t(C^{\dagger}_{i\sigma}C_{j\sigma}+ C^{\dagger}_{j\sigma}C_{i\sigma})+ J_H\Sigma_{i} \vec{S_i}\dot{C^{\dagger}_{i\alpha}\vec{\sigma_{\alpha\beta}}C_{i\beta}}
$$
where $ \vec{S_i} $ is an underlying spin texture, known as the local moment.

Comment: Hello Poulomi! Welcome to Physics SE. Could you give a little more context?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I am studying electrons in a lattice on a spin texture $\vec{S_i}$ . The Hamiltonian is mentioned. I am diagonalizing the Hamiltonian to get the energy eigenvalues and then I am calculating the density of states as a function of energy. This graph of density of states vs energy is not symmetric for me in some cases. I am asking if it should be.

Comment: Symmetric in what sense?

Comment: The density of states as a function of energy curve being symmetric. $\rho (E)$ being a symmetric function.